# How to access a ipv6 address using windows command?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, ipv6

I know how to access a ipv4 address using windows command.

Open command line and type

```
explorer.exe http://173.194.72.103
```

**Here is the question, how to access a ipv6 address?**

I tried to do this like ipv4

```
ping -6 www.google.com
```

result:Ping www.google.com [2607:f8b0:4006:808::1012]

```
explorer.exe http://2607:f8b0:4006:808::1012
```

or

```
explorer.exe https://2607:f8b0:4006:808::1012
```

Neither ok, they open "My Computer" panel.

Comment: Have you tried the same approach using an an ipv6 address? What is the issue/error? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes I do, but it didn't work. Thanks for reminding and I had update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I put `http://2607:f8b0:4006:808::1012` into the address bar of Google Chrome on Windows 7, it doesn't work (it searches for the "phrase" on Google).  Likewise for IE.  So I got to thinking, maybe your syntax is wrong, and it's not Explorer's fault.  And I found this:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n3jUQROi1cA

Which says you must use brackets.  And behold, this works:

```
explorer.exe http://[2607:f8b0:4006:808::1012]
```

The grammar is described in painstaking detail here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2

The key parts are:

```
host       = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name

IP-literal = "[" ( IPv6address / IPvFuture  ) "]"
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Can you teach me how to find these materials?